# Why would a read-in variable consumes way more memory than file's storage size in R

Tags: r, memory, read.table

When I tried to read in a big file of actual size 672MB into R, it turns out that the system memory usage exploded from 0.98 G to 3.6 G (I'm using a 4 GB memory desktop). Which means it takes several times of space to store the file into memory and I can do nothing calculation after I read in as lack of memory. Is that normal?
The code I've used: `a=read.table(file.choose(),header=T,colClasses="integer",nrows=16777777,comment.char="",sep="\t")`
The file contains 167772XX lines.

gc() before and after I run [image]

not sure what does this mean.

Comment: What happens if you run `gc()`, http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/gc.html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your text file is 672MB.  Assuming all your integers are 1 digit, it's perfectly reasonable that your R object is about 2*672MB.

Each character in a text file is 1 byte.  R stores integers in 4 bytes (see `?integer`).  That means your file contains ~336MB of `"\t"` and ~336MB of integers stored as 1-byte characters.

R reads those 1-byte characters, stores them as 4-byte integers and... 336*4 = 1344MB.  The second row and second column of your `gc` output reads 1345.6, which equals 1344MB + the original 1.6MB.

Comment: Thanks, but from 0.98 G to 3.6 G, there are ~2.6G used, by what you said, it used only ~1.3G, what about the other 1.3G?

Comment: @lolibility: `gc` reports max used of 2.62GB, which is because your object was copied inside of `read.table`.

Comment: So, is there a way to clean up those copied memories? If cleaned up, I would have 1.3G free and probably can do some calculation of my data.

Comment: @lolibility: That's what `gc` does, but it only makes the memory available to the OS; it doesn't mean the OS will immediately reclaim it.